How to Suppress "removing unused section ..." Messages in LLD 17.0.7
I am using the LLD 17.0.7 linker and encountering a large number of "removing unused section ..." messages in the output. These messages are cluttering my build logs.
Is there a way to suppress these specific messages without affecting the actual removal of the unused sections?
